# Visual Studio MySQL Database Project

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

Is there a way to make a database project in visual studio for MySQL?  Would I just create a normal database project and point it to a mysql database when I deploy?  Is there a project template out there for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of today (6/12/14) there is no way to create a MySQL Data Project in Visual Studio. This feature is however on the roadmap for MySQL, according to this enhancement request on the MySQL Website:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=59600

I suggest that you subscribe to that ticket so that you get notified when this feature becomes available.

Answer (score 5):

Some support is now available via [MySQL for Visual Studio](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/), albeit nowhere near as advanced as the SQL server support.